# Is there any difference between packages Rx-WPF and Rx-Xaml?

Tags: wpf, nuget, system.reactive

If I add the RX-main package to a WPF application I get the following dependent packages installed:

- Rx-Interfaces
- Rx-Core
- Rx-Linq
- Rx-PlatformServices
- Rx-Main

After adding Rx-main there are two additional packages related to WPF that can be installed

- Rx-XAML
- Rx-WPF

Rx-Xaml is dependent on Rx-Main, and Rx-WPF is dependent on Rx-Xaml. However both of these packages add a reference to System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.  What if anything is the difference between them, and why are there two separate packages that add a reference to the same assembly?

Also, do I need to add either or both to be able to use RX in WPF?

Comment: This is now the `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading` package

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I actually know the answer to this, as the former owner of the Rx-Xaml package. It used to be that there were only Rx-Silverlight and Rx-WPF. This made it difficult to create packages like [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net), since they had a dependency on one or the other *depending on which platform you're using*.

So, I created Rx-Xaml, which was literally just a merging of Rx-Silverlight and Rx-WPF. However, the Rx team realized that having separate packages was silly, and asked me if they could take over the name for themselves. I gladly obliged, and now Rx-Xaml is the package you should be using. Rx-Xaml since 2.0 is owned by Microsoft.

**tl;dr**: Use Rx-Xaml, ignore Rx-WPF and Rx-Silverlight, they're old and busted.

Answer (score -1):

From what I see using [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/), neither [Rx-WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-WPF/) not [Rx-Silverlight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Silverlight/) include any DLL of their own (or any other file, as a matter of fact) in their respective nupkg files. Therefore they seem to function only as a container for [Rx-Xaml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Xaml/). My guess is that you should still point to [Rx-WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-WPF/) since the Rx team might start adding specific logic to it which would not be contained in the base [Rx-Xaml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Xaml/) package.

Comment: What led me to this conclusion is that all the packages had the same version number. I was expecting the deprecated ones to have been left behind and have older version numbers, but I guess Rx-Xaml just hasn't needed updating at all.